# How to access the value of a nested object property that has been passed dinamically?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and have been practicing accessing objects. I would like to know if I'm accessing (checking in this case with an if statement) a nested object's property value correctly or not?

```
var object = {masterProp:
                     {propertyName:"value"}
             }

var propertyName = "propertyName";

if (object.masterProp[propertyName] === "value")
    // true or false?
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, does it work? More broadly, can you define what "*correctly*" means to you? This reads as a question that will elicit highly-opinionated answers and is not a good fit for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works correctly. You can use dot notations too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors.

Next time ask your question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

```js
var object = {masterProp:
                     {propertyName:"value"}
             }

var propertyName = "propertyName";

if (object.masterProp[propertyName] === "value") {
  console.log("true");
} else {
  console.log("false");
}
```